# How to remove a key from hashmap while iterating

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, key

i'm iterating over a hashmap, and comparing two keys. I remove the first key after saving it to a temp, so it never checks back through the keySet
I want to remove both keys (or at least not iterate over that particular key again) if its found to pair with a previous key

```
Iterator<Entry<Double, List<Double>>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Double, List<Double>> next = i.next();
    i.remove();

    for(Map.Entry<Double, List<Double>> e : map.entrySet()) {

        //if true they are a pair
        if((next.getKey() == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY && e.getKey() == 0) || (next.getKey() == 0 && e.getKey() == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || Math.abs(next.getKey() * e.getKey() + 1.0) < 0.0000001) {

            List<Double> arrayX = next.getValue();
            List<Double> arrayY = e.getValue();

            for(int a = 0; a < arrayX.size(); a++) {
                for(int b = 0; b < arrayY.size(); b++) {
                    if(Math.abs(arrayX.get(a) - arrayY.get(b)) < 0.0000001) {
                    squares++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

random example for a visual demo:

```
{1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6}
1 against {2,3,1,2,4,5,6}
when it reaches 1 remove it and perform a function
so the list left is {2,3,2,4,5,6}
repeat until all the list has been traversed
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I pair the keys if when you multiply them you get -1, the above was just an example